# unable to log out, which uses google/facebook oauth 2.0 and spring security

Tags: facebook, spring-security, google-api, oauth-2.0, logout

I'm able to log out from my website without actually deleting google/facebook cookies. I'm using spring security,

```
<a href='<c:url value='/j_spring_security_logout'/>'>Sign out</a>
```

This is just helping me logging out from my website, whats the procedure to completely logout i.e. i want to delete google/facebook user cookies, so that i can completely log out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the getLogoutURL() function from the SDK to logout the User from Facebook, and then redirect them to the security logout URL.

`https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next={site_logout_page}&access_token={access_token}`